# Problem with Okular (Navigation)

Tags: kde, okular

I've installed Okular 0.16.4 and am facing a little problem

Okular by default starts in navigation mode and presents you with other tools, like selection mode and such.

Problem is, everytime I try to change to any of those, It goes back to navigation mode!

Someone know how I can solve this?

Comment: What exactly are you changing?

Comment: I am trying to select part of the text. But it keeps using that hand.

Comment: Do you click on `Selection` fist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. 
It happens that, somehow, when I installed okular through kubuntu backport, it declared okularpartrc as being a root file. I simply had to change it's ownership to current user, and it now works.
(PS: I changed some other files in that folder to current user too, so... try this if okularpartrc isn't enough)
(PS2: /home/user/.kde/share/config/)

This is the place I found a solution
http://fr.it-usenet.org/thread/14140/13297/